# R function get rid of unused parameters in

Tags: r

I have a main function `mainFunction` that calls sub-functions :

- `subFunctionA`
- `subFunctionB`
- `subFunctionC`

Ideally I would like not to set manually all the "sub" parameters names in my `mainFunction` signature but use the `...` instead. However I get the `unused argument` error :

```
# Initial try
subFunctionA <- function(a = 1, b = 2) {a+b}
subFunctionB <- function(aa = 1, bb = 2) {aa+bb}
subFunctionC <- function(a = 1, bb = 2) {a+bb}

mainFunction <- function(...) {
  x1 <- subFunctionA(...)
  x2 <- subFunctionB(...)
  x3 <- subFunctionC(...)
  x1+x2+x3
}

mainFunction(a = 2, b = 2, aa = 3, bb = 4)
# Return error "Error in subFunctionA(...) : arguments inutilisés (aa = 3, bb = 4)"
```

Below the workaround I use, but I'm not sure I make good practice of additional parameters :

```
# Workaround
parameters_filters <- function(fun, ...) {
  p <- list(...)
  p[which(names(p) %in% names(as.list(args(fun))))]
}

mainFunction_workaround <- function(...) {
  x1 <- do.call(subFunctionA, parameters_filters(subFunctionA, ...))
  x2 <- do.call(subFunctionB, parameters_filters(subFunctionB, ...))
  x3 <- do.call(subFunctionC, parameters_filters(subFunctionC, ...))
  x1+x2+x3
}

mainFunction_workaround(a = 2, b = 2, aa = 3, bb = 4)
# Returns 17
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with the initial try:

```
subFunctionA <- function(a = 1, b = 2, ...) {a+b}
subFunctionB <- function(aa = 1, bb = 2, ...) {aa+bb}
subFunctionC <- function(a = 1, bb = 2, ...) {a+bb}

mainFunction <- function(...) {
  x1 <- subFunctionA(...)
  x2 <- subFunctionB(...)
  x3 <- subFunctionC(...)
  x1+x2+x3
}

mainFunction(a = 2, b = 2, aa = 3, bb = 4)
#[1] 17
```

This will cause issues if the user uses positional arguments:

```
mainFunction(2, 2, 3, 4)
#[1] 12
```

Thus, I would avoid `...` in the main function (unless you actually have optional parameters):

```
mainFunction <- function(a, b, aa, bb) {
  args <- list(a = a, b = b, aa = aa, bb = bb)
  x1 <- do.call(subFunctionA, args)
  x2 <- do.call(subFunctionB, args)
  x3 <- do.call(subFunctionC, args)
  x1+x2+x3
}

mainFunction(2, 2, 3, 4)
#[1] 17
```

And of course, not using `...` here at all would be the safest option.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand avoiding `...` would be the safest option but I know that my sub functions are likely to change in the futur and I don't want to change `mainFunction` as soon as a sub function signature changes.

Comment: That's your choice. It wouldn't be my choice.